# VLAN based interfaces for virtual machines

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, vlan

I am in the process of designing an experiment in which we have multiple VLANs arriving at a single NIC, with each VLAN being associated to a single VM.

The straightforward way to do this would be to set up tagged interfaces with vconfig and associate these interfaces with each of the VMs. I am somewhat worried about the impact this might have on performance (CPU utilization and latency), because I am not sure how the packets are rerouted to the specific virtual interfaces in the virtual hosts. Is there a way to do the same using the IOMMU, assuming that would enable direct access by applications in the VMs?

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution would be to create tagged interfaces, build a bridge on each and plug the VMs into the bridges.
With IOMMU you will probably be better off in terms of latency, but tagging on IOMMU is easier done inside the VM.

Just make sure the switch port is set to trunk.

As for load on the host, I've seen hosts with hundreds of tagged interfaces with no visible taxing on the host resources.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use IOMMU in this use case. IOMMU provides direct access to a complete physical PCI-e card for a VM.

In your case, since you want each VM to be on a different VLAN, you cannot provide the whole network interface via IOMMU, since it would also move all VLANs to that VM.

So, the only solution to achieve your goal is the one @dyasny wrote above, that is, create VLAN tagged interfaces (eth0.X) in host, and then bridge each interface to the VM.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way for the networking card to provide VLAN based RX & TX queues that could each be exposed via IOMMU. But judging from the answers so far, that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It turns out, what I wanted to do is easily possible with virtual functions in our case. Just configure each VF with the VLAN for the VM and voila, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for KVM but with vSphere it doesn't seem like a problem CPU-wise - I'm using several VLANs (tagged on the switch) on our production server and I can't speak of any noticeable change compared to the untagged one-VLAN-setting before.